# After Effects Add To Media Encoder Not Working

Tags: adobe, encoder, after-effects

I'm trying to use the after effect and i try to use Media Encoder to eksport composition to mp4
but always show error like this

[image]

here i solution i had try
https://community.adobe.com/t5/adobe-media-encoder-discussions/media-encoder-not-connecting-with-dynamic-link/td-p/10946429

but i don't understand about "Finder menu, Press Option Key then click Go, pick Library"
and i already delete adobe folder on document folder

i also had installed the same version of after effects and Media Encoder

[image]

Am I missing something??

I would be glad for any help.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to export the project as a MOV file directly from the render queue, and then use Media Encoder to convert the file to MP4.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall `Adobe Media Encoder`.
2. Open `Adobe After effect`. *(dont' close it)*
3. Install `Adobe Media Encoder`.

*Note :* If still you can't open `Media Encoder` from `After effect` open `Media Encoder` and from `Media Browser` window, open your `AEP` file and render it.